# Sync content item Api Issue

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am having an issue with syncing new content using Sync content item API.

I tried to add the new country in Sitecore Commerce Control Panel and try to sync the content by following the document in URL below

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/synchronize-content-items.html

After executing the `({{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/DoUxAction())` Sync content item api getting Ok Response. But new content items not synced in db.

`Sitecore Version Used: 9.0.2`

`Sitecore Commerce Version Used: 9.0.3`

Please let me know if any other information required.

Comment: Did you restart the Commerce Engine site after sync execution? You need to clean up Commerce Engine cache.

Comment: @andrei : Yes i have clean up Commerce Engine cache and IIS reset.

Comment: @ArunChauhan Did you check if the content entity for your new country has been actually created in the `ContentEntities` table in the `SharedEnvironment` database by the sync execution? This is an example of SQL query to find the country "Italy": 
`SELECT * FROM [ContentEntities] WHERE Entity like '%"TemplateName":"Country-Region"%' and Entity like '%Italy%'`

Comment: Can you post the response body after sending the {{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/DoUxAction()  ,from postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worst case you can do this:

1. Delete all entities from the ContentEntities table.
2. Delete all Entities from CommerceEntities table starting with `Content%`
3. Run `Ensure-Sync Content` to sync the whole control panel.

That usually always works for me as plan B.